# Total Requests made to DataSource = 0 when using SOLR with MySQL

Tags: mysql, solr

I followed the many tutorials on the web to get SOLR working with MySQL, but no matter which tutorial I follow, I always end up with "Total Requests made to DataSource = 0" in the fullimport command. I'm using an installation of Wordpress to test things out. The password for MYSQL is correct and the query is too. I downloaded the MySQL connector file again, but with no luck.

What my data-config.xml looks like:

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
          driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/wordpress" 
          user="root" 
          password="root"/>
   <document>
    <entity name="id" 
        query="select id,post_title from wp_posts">
    </entity>
   </document>
</dataConfig>
```

My SolrConfig.xml has this along with the other entries already in the file:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
  <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
 </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Should these be the only lines in SolrConfig.xml or am I supposed to add these lines along with the ones that are already there?

Comment: Is your database name correct? Does table *wp_posts* cointains records? How looks your `schema.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to my own problem. Apparently my MySQL connector file wasn't copied to the right location. Also I was on Ubuntu and I apt-get install'd the MySQL Java connector. I can't recall what that package was, but I think it did the trick.

Comment: Where did you copy the which package? Please give absolute answer not abstract.

Comment: Need to keep the 'mysql-connector-java-x.x.xx-bin.jar' in the '$SOLR_HOME/lib/' folder. $SOLR_HOME being the folder where your solr.xml exists. You would also be expected to keep the 'solr-dataimporthandler-x.xx.x.jar' in the same 'lib' folder. I faced the same issue, and it was resolved by moving the mysql connector file to the above mentioned location.